# Focusrite Scarlett and mic preamp

Tags: audio, live

I am going to purchase an 8i8 Scarlette Focusrite Audio Interface.  I will be running the outputs from the interface to my computer via USB.  My question is I'm not sure my Behringer dynamic mic will have enough power to get into the interface without having a pre-amp.

I have a couple of options in mind and I want someone's input:

1) Buy a cloud preamp for my mics prior to going into the Scarlett

2) Run my mic through my mixer and then into the Scarlette.

Which option is best?

Comment: Doesn't the Scarlett have mic preamps built in? (I couldn't find an 8i8 on the focusrite site - there's an 18i8?)

Comment: All of the Focusrite Scarlett interfaces have at least one mic preamp built in. If you connect to the Scarlett with an XLR cable, then you have connected to a mic preamp input.

Answer (score 4):

The XLR input of your Focusrite has a pre-amp so you can connect the dynamic mic in directly and have enough signal. You do not need an external mixer.

The Focusrite product line also provides phantom power for condenser microphones if you decide to use one of those.

In some cases an external microphone pre-amp may be more desirable than the built in pre-amp of the unit. High end tube driven pre-amps are sometimes used to provide a specific "color" to the mic signal, or are paired specifically to a particular mic.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your workflow, if I had an analog mixer (console), I would rather use my outputs on the interface to feed the console inputs, and the inputs of the Interface would connect to the console outputs, that way you can use your console and routes to record your mic, and then use your daw for playback.

I would also leave 2 channels connected from my console output or main to the interface to record the bounce with the console processes.

But if yours is a dj mixer go straight with the interface, you should not have a problem, interfaces are hooked up with a pre amp and with phantom power.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial option is:

1. Purchase the Scarlett interface.  Ttry the mic with it.

I don't think you'll find any further options necessary!  The mic inputs on this sort of interface generally have plenty of gain for anything other than a very low-output mic, and provide phantom power for mics that need it.

PS there's an 18i8 Scarlett.   Is that what you meant?    Are you going to get some more microphones?  4 mic inputs may be overkill?